# How can a preview of "Related Items" and "Subitems" be displayed prior to Publish?

Tags: publishing

We have a need to preview the number of subitems and related items prior to allow a publish to determine the impact on the publish queue when a publish is triggered.

So, instead of the "Publish" command here:

[image: Publish Item Modal]

There would be a "Preview" which would give some insight into the impact a triggered publish, such as the information here:

[image: Publish Progress Modal]

So, my questions are:

- Are there any modules that provide this function?
- If not, what is the hook to interrupt this process with a custom modal?
- Is this advisable?

Comment: None that I am aware of. Probably only way is to check through navigate/links ootb. Another option would be to create custom SPE script to show all related items for given item/subitems.

Answer (score 1):

In Sitecore, there is no `out-of-box` functionality to preview the number of subitems and related items prior to publishing.

However, it is possible to implement this functionality using `custom code` or `SPE` (Sitecore Powershell Extension) like `GetReferrers(item)` and `item.Axes.GetDescendants()` to get the changed items.

And in our project, we usually add a `Preview/QA` publishing target to the the Sitecore Publishing Service.

[image]

So you can get a preview UI with numbers and also see all changes presented for QA before publishing publicly.

There is a detailed reference at [Adding New Publishing Targets In Sitecore](https://www.getfishtank.com/blog/adding-new-publishing-targets-in-sitecore).

Hope it helps!